# Send template functionality in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Use case - We are integrating docusign on our web app. We have two user roles admin and coaches. Admins can create and edit templates and use it for sending envelopes but coaches can only use created templates to send envelopes. Is there a way to send templates so when a coach logs into the coach portal he can access the created templates.

Tech stack - java

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, templates can be shared to other DocuSign users. [See the docs](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-share-template).

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
You can create templates first using e Sign API, save them in DB with Template Name and Template ID(UUID which you get from DocuSign during creation)

Step 2:
Let your Coach login, then they can see templates, once they select template, you can use that template id to create envelope and send